# Search a value in JSON using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, search

```
<?php

$str = '[
    {
        "node":{
            "id": "bitcoin", 
            "name": "Bitcoin", 
            "price_usd": "610.471"
        }
    }, 
    {  
        "node":{
            "id": "ethereum", 
            "name": "Ethereum", 
            "price_usd": "12.0771"
        }
    }
]';

$result = json_decode($str, true);

$key = array_search('bitcoin', array_column($result,'node','id'));
echo $result[$key]['price_usd'];  // i need 610.471 here

?>
```

I have a long json code like above, I need to get the "price_usd" value by searching "id" name.
i dont want $str[0]["node"]["price_usd"]

Comment: Nothing to do with JSON parsing, since at the time you're searching, you don't use the JSON (`$str`) any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just iterate over the array and break when you get a hit:

```
foreach ($result as $k => $v) {
    if ($v['node']['id'] == 'bitcoin') break;
}
echo $result[$k]['node']['price_usd'];
```

The above code assumes that each sub-array has a key called `node` which also contains a key called `id`.  If you can't rely on those things you need to check on each iteration. I also assume you only need one value (the first one) since there could easily be multiple instances of `id` being equal to `bitcoin`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a double `array_column()` in order to get the list of prices by id:

```php
$prices_by_id = array_column(array_column($result, 'node'), 'price_usd', 'id');
```

This is needed because of the multiple nested levels in the original JSON string.

The value of `$prices_by_id`:

```
array(2) {
  ["bitcoin"]=>
  string(7) "610.471"
  ["ethereum"]=>
  string(7) "12.0771"
}
```

This way you can use `$prices_by_id['bitcoin']` to get its price.